# How to add libmp3lame, libx264, libvo_aacenc and libvorbis codecs to existing ffmpeg install on Redhat 6.7

Tags: ffmpeg, redhat, codec

Adobe cq uses **ffmpeg** to transcode videos. There is a workflow that is triggered when a user uploads any video to the digital asset management (DAM) section. This workflow internally uses ffmpeg to transcode the uploaded video and spits out additional video renditions in formats like **ogg, m4v, mp3**.

The server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5) on which adobe cq runs needs to have ffmpeg installed for the DAM workflow to function. ffmpeg has already installed been installed, but it is missing certain codecs: **libmp3lame, libx264, libvo_aacenc and libvorbis**.

How to add and enable these codecs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add support for arbitrary external libraries to an existing `ffmpeg` binary.

You'll either need to [download a new `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), or [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). Downloading a build is easiest and supports the encoders you listed (except libvo_aacenc). Compiling allows for customization.

Avoid libvo_aacenc: it provides poor quality and [support for libvo_aacenc has been removed from FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html#removing_external_aac_encoders). Use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder instead. See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any pointer to "Compiling allows for customization" howto ?

Comment: @rjn See the "compile `ffmpeg`" link I provided in the answer.